# What does `only: -master` in gitlab-ci.yml match?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file containing lines like

```
a_task:
  only:
    - /^production\/mybranch.*$/
```

which are clearly meant to match the target git ref.

But we also have:

```
another_task:
  only:
    - master
```

My question is: does this "`master`" match a part of the git ref as well (so that a tag `my-master-123` would match, too) or is it a symbolic thing?

The reason why am asking is that there is also:

```
third_task:
  only:
    - tags
```

That would have to be symbolic, right?

Which would mean that the syntax does e.g. **not** support a branch named `tags`, right?

### Update

Looks like there are [special keywords](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic), `tags` being one of them.

So indeed that would mean that refs with those special names (`external`, `pipelines`, `tags`, `triggers`, ...) would not be supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [the docs:](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#onlyexcept-basic)

> `only` and `except` are two keywords that set a job policy to limit when jobs are >created:
>
> 1. only defines the names of branches and tags the job runs for.
> 2. except defines the names of branches and tags the job does not run for.

Matching via regular expressions is supported, as in your first case, but not default. `only: master` tasks will run for all refs named `master`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But what about the value `tags` for `only`? That **would** have to be symbolic, wouldn't it?
I updated the questions to reflect this contradiction.

Comment: `tags` is special, as you say. if you really wanted to I suppose you can make a regex of it with `only: /^tags$/`, but that seems likely to just confuse. If you want something more than the reserved words and tag/branch matching via literal or regex comparison, you should use the more advanced options